# "Instruments crashed on startup" Appium on iOS Real Device?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, appium

I got error  "  **A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 22.44 seconds** " while using Appium for iOS Automation.

Configuration :-
XCode 7.3
iPhone 5S -- Version 10

Please suggest with Steps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work for you but i solve the problem like below:

first, open xcode and open

```
xcode > window > devices
```

there you will see all of your available device and simulator.

```
Right click on the device name and delete the device.
```

Now at bottom, you will see a "+" icon, click there and Add device.

```
Now go to the xcode > open developer tool > instruments and click on it.

After opening the instruments, Double click on "Automation" option which is on top 4 from left.
```

Now click on the red mark area in the attached image:

[image]

After clicking on that, you will see your device in the list. select the device

and wait for a while and restart the xcode.

Hope this will help you